# Trigger action creator on onchange of a field in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am newbie to redux .I'm trying to create an application using redux-form. Could you please help me how to trigger an action when any changes happen in any of the field in the form .

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
    import { Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';

    const renderField=({ input, label,name, type, meta})=>(
        <FormGroup row>
                        <Label for={name} sm={2}>{label}</Label>
                        <Col sm={10}>
                        <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}></input>
                         </Col>
        </FormGroup>
    )


    const BreakupForm=(props)=>{
        console.log(props);
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
        return(
            <div>
            <Label >Breakup</Label>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

             <Field label="Basic" name="basic" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="basic"/>
             <Field label="HRA" name="hra" component={renderField}  type="text" placeholder="HRA"/>
             <Field label="Transport Allowance" name="ta"  component={renderField}  type="text" placeholder="Transport Allowance" />
             <Field label="Special Allowance" name="specialAllowance" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Special Allowance" />
             <Field label="LTA" name="lta" component={renderField}  type="text" placeholder="LTA"/>
             <Field label="Medical Bills"  name="medicalBills" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Medical Bills"/>
            </form>
            </div>

        )
    }


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'breakupForm' // a unique identifier for this form
  })(BreakupForm)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to trigger action on change  other than creating onchange action on each Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChange` on every field you want to observe, for instance:

```
<Field label="Basic" name="basic" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="basic" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
```

and then write your `onChangeHandler` which will be called with the following parameters:

`event, newValue, previousValue, name`

For instance, looking at your code, you can listen to field `basic` changes like this:

```
const BreakupForm = (props) => {

  const onBasicFieldChange = (event, newValue, previousValue, name) => {
    console.log(newValue)
  }

  console.log(props);
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <div>
      <Label >Breakup</Label>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field onChange={onBasicFieldChange} label="Basic" name="basic" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="basic" />
        <Field label="HRA" name="hra" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="HRA" />
        <Field label="Transport Allowance" name="ta" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Transport Allowance" />
        <Field label="Special Allowance" name="specialAllowance" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Special Allowance" />
        <Field label="LTA" name="lta" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="LTA" />
        <Field label="Medical Bills" name="medicalBills" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="Medical Bills" />
      </form>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: this works with action creator .change? fire onChange?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to Redux Form documentation, [Redux Form onChange callback](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-name-gt-void-code-optional-)

Field component accepts a prop (onChange), you can pass a function to the onChange props.

```
 <Field label="Basic" onChange={this.handleChange} name="basic" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="basic"/>
```

handleChange will be a function defined in your class.

Since your component is stateless component, you can passs the callback function through props

```
<Field label="Basic" onChange={props.handleChange} name="basic" component={renderField} type="text" placeholder="basic"/>
```

Comment: your answer is not complete.